# Scrolling down recyclerview to bottom in mvvm

Tags: java, android, mvvm, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

Im implementing mvvm and databinding in my application. Im using the bellow code to set recyclerview adapter

```
@BindingAdapter({"bind:setAdapter"})
public static void setUpAdapter(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.Adapter adapter) {
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

and layout contains

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    tools:itemCount="2"
    tools:listitem="@layout/chat_bubble_left"
    app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    app:setAdapter="@{chatViewModel.chatMessageAdapter}"/>
```

The adapter is contained inside a viewModel

What i need is i want to call

```
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(items.size() - 1);
```

From where i call this method and
What is the best practice to reference the recyclerview to call this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer after some trial and errors.
This can be accomplished by using an observableInt which should be set each time to (list-1) while updating the list .

```
public ObservableInt scrollTo=new ObservableInt();
```

....

```
 list.addAll(templist);
 chatMessageAdapter.notifyItemInserted(list.size()-1);                
 chatMessageAdapter.scrollTo.set(list.size()-1);
```

and use

```
app:scrollTo="@{chatViewModel.chatMessageAdapter.scrollTo}
```

in RecyclerView element in layout

an set binding adapter as

```
@BindingAdapter({"bind:scrollTo"})
public static void scrollTo(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position) {
    recyclerView.scrollToPosition(position);
}
```